# Logstash Reached end of file

Tags: logstash

I am attampting to run multiple logstash parsers once after another due to memory constraints and I am wondering if there is a way to check if a logstash instance has reached the end of file for a set of files.

Once this info appears in a log file, I can turn off that parser and start another set. and so on and so forth.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `file` input plugin then when it reaches the end of the file, it just waits for more to be written to it.

Logstash isn't meant to shut down after processing a file.

If you're looking for something to watch a directory and process files, you may be better served looking into an ETL or Workflow tool.

Have you taken a look at [Apache Nifi](https://nifi.apache.org/)?

Comment: I dont need logstash to shut down when it reaches EOF, I just need some kind of acknowledge. I can turn on and off with a script.

Comment: it has no concept of end of the file.  From their docs: `Stream events from files, normally by tailing them in a manner similar to tail -0F but optionally reading them from the beginning.`